# Install scipy and numpy on Win 64 machine (python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

*I know there have been questions similar to this one before - I read them all and tried what they suggested*

Hi,
I'm trying to install the scipy and numpy modules on my win 64 machine so I could call them from my IDE of choice. Alas, all my efforts were in vein.
Here's what I tried:

**1)** according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213551/installing-scipy-with-pip) I tried installing with pip. Even though the comments praise the solution is one with longevity, when I ran

```
pip install git+http://github.com/scipy/scipy/
```

I got an error:

```
C:\Python27>pip install git+http://github.com/scipy/scipy/
Downloading/unpacking git+http://github.com/scipy/scipy/
  Cloning http://github.com/scipy/scipy/ to c:\users\____\ap
\pip-vguqfv-build
Cleaning up...
Cannot find command 'git'
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\____\pip\pip.log
```

and when I tried:

```
pip install git+http://github.com/scipy/scipy/
```

I got:

```
Downloading/unpacking scipy
  Running setup.py (path:c:\users\XXXX\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_XXXX
\scipy\setup.py) egg_info for package scipy

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*_subr_*.f' found under dire
ctory 'scipy\linalg\src\id_dist\src'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\source\generated'
    no previously-included directories found matching '*\__pycache__'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found anywhere in distri
bution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.bak' found anywhere in dis
tribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.swp' found anywhere in dis
tribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in dis
tribution
Installing collected packages: scipy
  Running setup.py install for scipy
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\XXXX\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_XXXX\scipy\setup.
py", line 237, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "c:\users\XXXX\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_XXXX\scipy\setup.
py", line 225, in setup_package
        from numpy.distutils.core import setup
    ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils.core
    Complete output from command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, t
okenize;__file__='c:\\users\\XXXX\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip_build_XXXX\
\scipy\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().
replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\XXXX\ap
pdata\local\temp\pip-xpcgro-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externall
y-managed --compile:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "c:\users\XXXX\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_XXXX\scipy\setup.py",
 line 237, in <module>

    setup_package()

  File "c:\users\XXXX\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_XXXX\scipy\setup.py",
 line 225, in setup_package

    from numpy.distutils.core import setup

ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils.core

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\use
rs\\XXXX\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip_build_XXXX\\scipy\\setup.py';exec(co
mpile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __
file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\XXXX\appdata\local\temp\pip-xpcg
ro-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile faile
d with error code 1 in c:\users\XXXX\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_XXXX\s
cipy
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\XXXX\pip\pip.log
```

**2)** Tried to grab the 64 bit installers from [Christoph Gohlke's page](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) like so many places [suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2114531/2594546), including [scipy.org](http://www.scipy.org/) itself, but I tried multiple times, from multiple machines at multiple locations, the downloads always ultimately failed.

**3)** Installed [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads.html). Scipy and Numpy are available in IPython now, which is better than nothing but in all honestly I'm not used to the IPython interface and like pyscripter better. Even though I can import Scipy and Numpy alright in IPython, I can in pyscripter or even in the cmd console. Similar results with Canopy, where it's only available within the Canopy IDE.

**4)** Can't download the binaries directly from sourceforge (e.g. [scipy on sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/)), as they are all for win 32.

So, to get to my question..... what can I do (if anything?).
Would appreciate your help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [Winpython](http://winpython.sourceforge.net/) or [Python (x,y)](https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/). These distributions provide full functionality for your purpose, have all neccessary packages precompiled (I you install them via pip, you need to compile C and Fortran code) and the packages included are all checked for compatibility with each other.

Comment: Will they then be available for import on all IDEs ?

Comment: Just set the Path to Python in the IDE to where you installed it.