# Installing Numpy 1.9.2 for Python 2.7.10 on a 64-bit Windows operating system?

Tags: python, windows, numpy, 64-bit, pip

Last night I tried installing Numpy on Windows 8. I have Python 2.7.10 installed on my Windows 8.1 Pro machine. Initially I realized that the only way to easily install Numpy is to install the 1.3 version[1] , which is pretty old. Then I found out that pip can install Numpy, but since my OS is a 64-bit one I cannot use pip directly and have to first deal with Cython, Fortran and other stuffs' installation [2]. In the end I followed the instruction given in [3] and [4] but the error that I get is non of the errors described in [3]. I may mention that I upgraded "wheel" to the latest version before downloading the **unofficial**, compiled Numpy file downloaded from [5]. The error message that I get is as follows:

> numpy-1.9.2+mkl-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on
>   this platform.

Could you please help me how I can resolve this issue?

Thank you

[1] [How do I install SciPy on 64 bit Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517129/python-how-do-i-install-scipy-on-64-bit-windows)

[2] [Installing NumPy and SciPy on 64-bit Windows (with Pip)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657334/installing-numpy-and-scipy-on-64-bit-windows-with-pip)

[3] [How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows?rq=1)

[4] https://gehrcke.de/2015/02/how-to-set-up-a-64-bit-version-of-numpy-on-windows/

[5] http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

Comment: Use the Anaconda, it includes everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

Something similar happened to me, the point is that even the system be 64-bit,  install the 32-bit version, the installation will occur usually when I did that worked with matplotlib and numpy.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.9.2/numpy-1.9.2-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe/download