# Can't import sklearn and scipy. Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I'm trying to set all of this up on Windows 7. This is the error I get when I try to import sklearn or scipy. I've installed sklearn and scipy using whl files. I don't remember what I used to install numpy but I can import numpy without trouble.

[image: The error]

Comment: Probably relevant [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37281256/5781248)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: cannot import name NUMPY\_MKL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267399/importerror-cannot-import-name-numpy-mkl)

Comment: It's possible that your binary-installs are not compatible. E.g. installing official numpy binaries, but then scipy from Gohlke's builds. Not necessarily broken, but still possible. I recommend removing *everything* and starting from scratch keeping in mind, that not everything is compatible with everything else. Or just use [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/why-anaconda), which is the easiest way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case [I couldn't install scipy using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575587/cant-install-scipy-through-pip) `pip install scipy`, I finally managed to get it installed by using Scipy from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy), and installing it as follows:

```
pip3 install scipy-0.19.0rc2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

When I finally had scipy installed, my numpy stopped working and started giving that error. So I decided to install numpy from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy):

```
pip3 install numpy-1.12.0+mkl-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

*Make sure that you install the correct numpy for your architecture and version of Python.*

I hope that helps you, cheers.