# Python installation and run time error in windows

Tags: python

When i run the python code

```
from numpy._distributor_init import NUMPY_MKL  # requires numpy+mkl
```

The following error is shown:

```
ImportError: No module named 'numpy._distributor_init'
```

Comment: Have you added SciPy library?

Comment: Yes I added Scipy Numpy pip also....

Comment: Check, This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267399/importerror-cannot-import-name-numpy-mkl

Comment: I try this command but now it shown this error  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import scipy
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    from numpy._distributor_init import NUMPY_MKL  # requires numpy+mkl
ImportError: No module named 'numpy._distributor_init'