# Python 3.5 (32-bit): ImportError: cannot import name NUMPY_MKL

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I am new to Python and I am trying to install numpy+mkl and scipy (in the same order), but I get below error when I execute following steps:

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np  
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
```

I am using Python 3.5 (32-bit) on a Windows 7 64-bit OS.

There is a similar question already answered for the exact problem here: [ImportError: cannot import name NUMPY_MKL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267399/importerror-cannot-import-name-numpy-mkl)

Going through the answer, I reinstalled my numpy+mkl pkg `numpy‑1.11.2+mkl‑cp35‑cp35m‑win32.whl` from the mentioned link (http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) and then reinstalled `scipy-0.18.1-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl` as well, but that does not solve the problem and I still get the same error:

```
>>> exec(open("C:\\PythonFiles\\testpy1.py").read())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\msoudagar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python3532\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\Users\msoudagar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scipy import sparse
  File "C:\Users\msoudagar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python3532\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    from numpy._distributor_init import NUMPY_MKL  # requires numpy+mkl
ImportError: cannot import name 'NUMPY_MKL'
```

Any inputs would be really helpful!

Comment: In the error message there's a path with `Python3532` and another with `Python35-32`. That seems fishy. Also, since you're reinstalling, why not use 64-bit python?

Answer (score 1):

Try commenting out the line
`from numpy._distributor_init import NUMPY_MKL`
it might just work regardless.

[ImportError: cannot import name NUMPY_MKL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267399/importerror-cannot-import-name-numpy-mkl)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not the most sophisticated of solutions but, all I had to do was close the IDE(in my case, Pycharm) and re-open it again.

Not sophisticated but effective in my case :).

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer. Solved my problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37294205/2708266

Suggesting to download ready made binary setup from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

```
pip install xx.whl
```

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same issue on Windows with Python 3.5 64 bit. Manually installing numpy+mkl from wheel file solved the issue for me.
Select the appropriate wheel file from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) (cp35,win32 for you):  and install it using `pip install --user Path_to_local_file.whl` replacing Path_to_local_file with wherever you saved the .whl file

This is a also a duplicate of [ImportError: cannot import name NUMPY_MKL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267399/importerror-cannot-import-name-numpy-mkl)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16330081)

Comment: Thanks for the Feedback. I also just realized this Question is 6 months old.. So my answer is probably not going to be relevant anyway

Comment: It doesn't matter if the question is old, you can still answer it. Even if your answer might not help the person who asked the question, it can still help others who are looking for an answer to the same problem and found this question by googling. You're even encouraged to answer old questions, there are badges for that: [Revival](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/837/revival) and [Necromancer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer). For more information, you can read [Should I answer an old (inactive) question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265642/4284627)