# Python ImportError - NUMPY MKL

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

I keep getting this error whenever I try running this code, if I can get some insight in what is going on that would be a great help, since I'm pretty new to this coding environment I would really appreciate some help. The code is this:

> File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Python\pythonsimulation.py", line 6, in 
>       from scipy import *
>     File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy__init__.py", line 61, in 
>       from numpy._distributor_init import NUMPY_MKL  # requires numpy+mkl
>   ImportError: cannot import name 'NUMPY_MKL'

Am I missing some package or module that python requires in order to run the code?

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267399/importerror-cannot-import-name-numpy-mkl)

Answer (score 4):

**Reason:**
This error indicates that `numpy` is missing `NUMPY_MKL`. This usually happens when you have installed `scipy` from `.whl` (Pre-compiled File). To resolve this.

**Solution:**
Download `numpy+MKL` wheel(.whl) from following link and install using pip.
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

Comment: after downloading what next?

Comment: install the downloaded `.whl` file using:
`pip install  numpy+mkl.whl` 
where `numpy+mkl.whl` is the file you downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jupyter, try restarting the kernel. please click Restart in Kernel menu.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is no problem. Just need to restart the Jupyter and you will see it is working well.