# Import Seaborn Error - Numpy_MKL (Python Script)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I coded in `jupyter-notebook`, fetching data from `mysqlserver` and then downloaded it as a `python` script because I want to implement it in my website using `cronjob`. So when I run the `Python` script, I'm getting this error:

```
import seaborn as sns
  File "C:\Users\Debadri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\seaborn\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .rcmod import *
  File "C:\Users\Debadri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\seaborn\rcmod.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import palettes, _orig_rc_params
  File "C:\Users\Debadri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\seaborn\palettes.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .utils import desaturate, set_hls_values, get_color_cycle
  File "C:\Users\Debadri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\seaborn\utils.py", line 7, in <module>
    from scipy import stats
  File "C:\Users\Debadri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    from numpy._distributor_init import NUMPY_MKL  # requires numpy+mkl
ImportError: cannot import name 'NUMPY_MKL'
```

I tried to install `numpy+mkl` `.whl` file from this link: [Numpy+MKL](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy), this (`numpy‑1.15.1+mkl‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl`)  package, but it showed, not supported when I tried to install it.

Comment: try `pip install mkl` and see what happens.

Comment: nope not fixed :(

Comment: maybe do a `import numpy; numpy.show_config()` and post the output. also `pip list` might be helpful.

Comment: there's no problem in importing `numpy` as well as `scipy` as well as `seaborn` also. `seaborn` is working just fine in IPYNB

Comment: `numpy.show_config()` will show your whether mlk is used or not. this has nothing to do with importing.

Comment: also you can try `pip install intel-scipy` but always make sure you remove other numpy, scipy packages first!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution worked out:

Solution:
If you are using windows make sure you install numpy+mkl instead of just numpy.
If you have already installed scipy and numpy, uninstall then using "pip uninstall scipy" and "pip uninstall numpy"

Now download scipy from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy (appropriate version for your python and system)
and install using "pip install  scipy‑1.1.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl" (Please install from the list according to your system config)

Your numpy and Scipy both should work now. 
These binaries by Christoph Gohlke makes it very easy to install python packages on windows. But make sure you download all the dependent packages from there.

Reference: 4th answer of this question [ImportError: cannot import name NUMPY_MKL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267399/importerror-cannot-import-name-numpy-mkl)