# Which scipy wheel to install for Windows 7?

Tags: python, windows, scipy, 64-bit, python-wheel

I'm running 64 bit python 2.7 on Windows 7.

There are wheels for scipy at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scipy

In the above link, which wheel is for scipy for 64-bit Windows?

Answer (score 2):

Try installing through-
scipy-0.19.0.zip (md5, pgp)
extract the folder and run following command after setting the directories-
**python setup.py install**
(setup.py is contained in extracted folder)

If you not able to install it, try doing it through wheel-

```html
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy
```

Download scipy-0.19.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl and place it in python folder.
Install scipy by-
**pip install scipy-0.19.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl**

Answer (score 1):

As it is mentioned here:

> Windows does not have any package manager analogous to that in Linux, so installing one of the scientific Python distributions mentioned above is preferred. However, if that is not an option, Christoph Gohlke provides pre-built Windows installers for many Python packages, including all of the core SciPy stack, which work extremely well.
>
> -- [Source](https://www.scipy.org/install.html)

[Here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) is the link for windows installers(unofficial) for scipy. Also, check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517129/how-do-i-install-scipy-on-64-bit-windows?rq=1) too.

Comment: Windows has `pip` and they are just wrong by not releasing wheels for Windows.